Popup "отцепляется" от ComboBox JavaFX
Не могу понять как решить проблему с закреплением Popup-a к расположению ComboBox. То есть, я при смещении приложения Popup остается на месте.



Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

На macOS при смещении окна элементы ComboBox автоматически скрываются. Возможно недочет в пользовательском интерфейсе вашей ОС.

То есть остается вариант с созданием собственного Control?

Если программы от других разработчиков содержащие этот виджет не имеют такой проблемы, значит да, надо настраивать. Проверьте обновлена ли javafx до последней версии и, по возможности, протестируйте свой код на других ОС.
